# Mixpanel Surveyactivity - how to change the style?

Tags: android, android-notifications, mixpanel

I am using Mixpanel for in-app notifications, using the guide here : https://mixpanel.com/help/reference/android-inapp-notifications#integration

In my Android Manifest, I have set my usual application's theme to the be the SurveyActivity's theme, however, I still find the SurveyActivity (when a survey comes up) to be having the  default Mixpanel's SurveyActivity (translucent) theme

### Android manifest:

```
<application
    android:name="com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.globalstate.App"
    android:allowBackup="true"

    android:icon="@drawable/earthmiles_logo_green"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:logo="@drawable/earthmiles_logo_white_actionbar"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"

    android:theme="@style/Theme.Emgreen_actionbar"
    tools:replace="android:icon">

    <meta-data android:name="com.mixpanel.android.MPConfig.ResourcePackageName" android:value="com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles" />

    <meta-data android:name="com.mixpanel.android.MPConfig.AutoShowMixpanelUpdates"
        android:value="false" />



    <activity
        android:name="com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.views.MainActivity_"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity
        android:name="com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.views.ActivityLanding_"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

   ...
   ...



    <activity android:name="com.mixpanel.android.surveys.SurveyActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Emgreen_actionbar"/>        // does not seem to change the theme of surveyactivity

    ...


    ...
</application>
```

Also, is there a way of just seeing how the SurveyActivity looks like without waiting helplessly for a notificaiton or survey from mixpanel servers to arrive? I tried invoking using an intent, but does not work:

### in MainActivity.java

```
    Intent surveyActivityIntent = new Intent(this, SurveyActivity.class);
    startActivity(surveyActivityIntent);
```

> 8628-8628/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug
>   E/MixpanelAPI.SurveyActivity﹕ SurveyActivity intent received, but
>   nothing was found to show.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question and I just contacted the MixPanel support team and they told me so far there is no way to customize the surveys yet.... That is too bad, they told me maybe in the future they are adding this function but so far there is no way